# Meaning of the SCI Magazines and Conference indexed by SCOPUS

Tags: computer-science, scopus

I don't know the meaning of two above. Can anyone explain to me? For example is [this article](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3293882.3330551?casa_token=kgllsDhk8GcAAAAA:vwDAJogr7xHRZx3MsJbZu8MS9UTMKHDLT4soihBJfDElLwuaZ0IoYQO_L8egB_VMxpI_IwEIrhXhHg) one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCI refers to 'Science Citation Index' and forms one part of *[Web of Science](https://webofscience.com/)*, a database of scholarly publications.

*[Scopus](https://www.scopus.com/search/form.uri?display=basic)* is another database of scholarly publications (a competitor).

Both databases selectively index academic journals and conferences after a certain quality-control, which is why some people (research evaluators, funders) may place a specific value to such Web of Science- or Scopus-indexed outlets.

Regarding your specific paper, yes, it is:

- indexed within Web of Science in the *Conference Proceedings Citations Index* (CPCI), but not in SCI because it is a conference paper and not a journal publication (record ID: WOS:000503498000030)
- indexed in Scopus (record ID: 2-s2.0-85070598252)